# How to get this javascript array from php array?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript array

```
<script>
var image = document.getElementById('example-basic');

var options = {};
var data = [
  Taggd.Tag.createFromObject({
    position: { x: 0.19, y: 0.4 },
    text: 'This is a tree',
  }),
  Taggd.Tag.createFromObject({
    position: { x: 0.5, y: 0.3 },
    text: 'Pretty sure this is also a tree',
  }),
  Taggd.Tag.createFromObject({
    position: { x: 0.775, y: 0.5 },
    text: 'Can you guess this one?',
  }),
];

var taggd = new Taggd(image, options, data);
</script>
```

I need to create a PHP array and covert it into this javascript array can you please help me?

Comment: I cannot see any php array in your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Use json_encode function :  https://eval.in/752831

Comment: i want create this array dynamic using php? how will i do?

Comment: javascript data array needs to be converted from php array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in PHP, but I am sure you could output an html from php:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var js_ar = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
</script>
```

js_ar will be a global variable when javascript is executed on browser and can be easily accessed. I would leave variable naming up to you.

Comment: i need php array of the given javascript array

Comment: what will be that php array

Comment: Are you asking here that you need to convert JavaScript Array to PHP ? If yes, then Gyandeep Sharma answer is correct.

Comment: I am hoping that you are aware and understand that PHP code would run in server and Javascript code runs on browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem

PHP Code: `<?php $your_php_array=array(0,10); ?>`

JS:

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo json_encode($your_php_array) ?>;
for (var x in data) {
    document.write(x + "<br>");
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by ajax only. send this js variable data to

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'PATH_TO_DESTINATION',
    type        : 'POST',
    data        : {'array_var': you_array_variable},
    success     : function(e) {}
});
```

DESTINATION PAGE

```
<?php
    $array_var = $_POST['array_var'];
    $ar=explode(',',$array_var);
    print_r($ar);
?>
```

Comment: i need php array of the given javascrpt array

Comment: what will be this your_php_array?

Comment: i need to convert php array to javascript array